# Make col-6 take up full row when other col-6 hides on small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am currently working with two columns

```
<div class="col-6">
  <p>
   paragraph text goes here
  </p>
</div>

<div class="col-6 d-none d-sm-block">
  <img class="goal-f1 rounded" src="img/rubbish.jpg">
</div>
```

The column with the image is set to hide on small screens, I am wondering if it's possible for the other column to take up the full row when the column hides?

Right now it just leaves a huge empty space where the image used to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add responsive column classes:

```
<div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
  <p>paragraph text goes here</p>
</div>    
<div class="col-6 d-none d-sm-block">
  <img class="goal-f1 rounded" alt="rubbish.jpg" src="img/rubbish.jpg">
</div>
```

Like this, the element with the paragraph child will take the full row's length whenever the viewport is smaller than `sm` breakpoint.